# Android strange SSL fail

Tags: android, ssl

Writing here about a strange behavior I have on some devices. For what I know, there are at least 2 impacted devices, a *Samsung Core 4G* and a *Start Trail 5*, but I don't know if there are some others with the same problem.

Here is the point, I have an API, which is secured with SSL and the certificate is **NOT** self-signed, it is verified by **Thawte, Inc.**

For almost all devices, using the API works fine, but on the two above, the SSL Handshake fails and the device acts like the website is somewhat malicious (certificate not verified).

I checked in the *Settings* and the *Thawte, Inc.* is checked in the providers.

The problem is everywhere on the phone, our app, Chrome, Firefox or any browser. I tried to *reboot*, *wipe* the phone, *(un|re)install apps*, but no way.

What could be the problem?

Comment: just because "thawte" is checked doesn't mean much. most ssl providers have MULTIPLE types of certs provided, and each is a unique chain as far as ssl libs are concerned. e.g. you'll have "Acme, Inc." checked off, which internally has "type 1" and "type 2" certs allowed, and then you come across "Acme Inc, type 3" and boom... untrusted.

Comment: Ok, think I get it.
But what can I do ? Or how can I check that ? I mean, it is working fine on every devices except these 2. 
Is it possible for the phone to be *outdated* ?

Comment: How are you doing the certificate validation? Perhaps the certificate contains extensions that are unsupported by the validator on those devices that you mentioned? Are you able to add additional logs to find out more about why the handshake fails?

Comment: Maybe, the device is not available currently, I just saw the SSL Failure in some logs but nothing very verbose. 
I'll do a full log to see if something is showing up from that.